# This Unity Jumping & Gravity script is a mess, how can I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Jump Properties")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpTime;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpMultiplier;
    [SerializeField] private float fallMultiplier;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private float groundCheckRadius = .02f;
    [SerializeField] private float mGroundedTimer;
    [SerializeField] private float mSpaceRemember;

    private bool grounded;
    public float cGroundedTimer;
    private float cSpaceRemember;
    private float jumpCounter;
    private bool isJumping;
    private Vector2 vecGravity;
    private PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    public Rigidbody2D rb; 

    private Vector2 boxSize = new Vector2(0.6f, 0.2f);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        vecGravity = new Vector2(0, -Physics2D.gravity.y);
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheck.position, boxSize, 0, groundLayer);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        

        ResetTimers();

        if (cGroundedTimer > 0 && cSpaceRemember > 0)
        {
            Jump();
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && isJumping)
        {
            jumpCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            if (jumpCounter > jumpTime) isJumping = false;


            rb.velocity += vecGravity * jumpMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && isJumping)
        {
            isJumping = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y / 2);
        }


        cGroundedTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        cSpaceRemember -= Time.deltaTime;

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && isJumping)
        {
            jumpCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            
            if (jumpCounter > jumpTime)
            {
                isJumping = false;
                Debug.Log("Penis");
            }


            rb.velocity += vecGravity * jumpMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity -= vecGravity * fallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        

        
    }

    void ResetTimers()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            cGroundedTimer = mGroundedTimer;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            cSpaceRemember = mSpaceRemember;
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        cGroundedTimer = 0;
        cSpaceRemember = 0;
        isJumping = true;

        jumpCounter = 0;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Define the size of the box based on your ground check size
        Vector2 boxSize = new Vector2(0.7f, 0.2f);

       
        // Set the Gizmo color to green if grounded, red if not
        Gizmos.color = grounded ? Color.green : Color.red;

        // Draw a wire cube at the ground check's position with the specified box size
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(groundCheck.position, new Vector3(boxSize.x, boxSize.y, 0));
    }


}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this and make it less spaghetti? If I try to break it up into seperat functions it just stops working.

#############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you think is wrong with it? It looks fine to me. Since you haven't shown the trouble you had when refactoring it we can't comment on that.